# Extending root partition into allocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, btrfs, unallocated

I know there are several questions about this topic, but none of them appear to help me.

When I first started using Ubuntu, I used Windows Disk Manager to shrink the NTFS partition that came with my computer so that I could dual boot Ubuntu.  Now, I'm barely using Windows anymore, and so I'd like to extend my root partition.  I shrunk the Windows partition from within Windows to create a bunch of unallocated space adjacent to my BTRFS partition.  However, GParted is not giving me the option to extend my root partition--only to shrink it.  Here is a screenshot of GParted:

[image]

I'd like to extend SDA7 to the left using the 397 GB of unallocated space next to it.  However, when I click "resize/move partition," it tells me that SDA7 is already the maximum size.

Comment: First of all, you need to do it from a live session, not from your installed system (you probably stumbled upon this info several times in the other questions you mentioned but since you posted a screenshot when running the installed Ubuntu, I think this reminder is warranted). Then you need to **move** `sda7` all the way to the right before resizing.

Comment: In Ubuntu you have to boot from LiveUSB to mess with the partitions where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: Do your backups before managing partitions. There's always the possibility of data loss and moving+resizing is riskier than just resizing.

Comment: @MichaelBay running from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB is correct. But I don't understand **moving** sda7 to the right? You can't.

Comment: @heynnema Good catch! **I meant moving to the *left***, obviously.

Comment: @MichaelBay does the BTRFS require a move (left) and resize from the right side to be able to resize? His error message indicates that the partition is already at its max size. EXT4 doesn't require that (although that's what I usually do).

Comment: @heynnema That is also what I always do and I suppose the error has to do with it. Being able to resize in the OP's case or similar without moving it is news to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, including those of @MichaelBay and @user68186, and myself...

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda7 all the way to the left
- **resize** the right side of sda7 all the way to the right
- if it looks good, click on the "Apply" icon
- when complete, quit `gparted`
- reboot